# jq json parser appends JSON field based on conditions

Tags: json, jq

I have the below input file:

```
[
{
    "macAddress": "22:00:10:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 1.2345,
        "longitude": 123.4567,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    }
},
{
    "macAddress": "44:00:10:21:ca:14"
},
{
    "macAddress": "33:00:11:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    }
},
...
]
```

I would like to use `jq` program to parse the JSON to get the below output

```
[
"created_at": "2016-04-13T14:50:03+0800", 
{
    "macAddress": "22:00:10:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 1.2345,
        "longitude": 123.4567,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    },
    "loc": {
        "lon": 123.4567,
        "lat": 1.2345
    }
},
{
    "macAddress": "44:00:10:21:ca:14"
},
{
    "macAddress": "33:00:11:21:ca:54",
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
    },
    "loc": {
        "lon": 123.45678,
        "lat": 2.1345544523
    }
},
...
]
```

You can see that I have inserted `created_at` field.

I have also added lat/long pair based on the condition of the `GeoCoordinate` field exist or not.

How to use `jq` to achieve that?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid json. You cannot put a property on an array. `ISODate("2016-04-13T14:50:03+0800")` is not a valid json value.

Comment: @JeffMercado, I have changed the output to valid json after read your comment.

Comment: Your output is still not valid json. `[ "foo: "bar", { "a" : "b", ... }]` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally adding the lat/long pair should be simple.  Just check if you have a `GeoCoordinate` value and add the pair.  Your `created_at` property is invalid at that location, so here's the closest that we can do:

```
{
    created_at: now | todate,
    results: map(
        if .GeoCoordinate then
            .loc = (.GeoCoordinate | { lon: .longitude, lat: .latitude })
        else
            .
        end
    )
}
```

This would yield the following results:

```
{
  "created_at": "2016-04-19T20:09:35Z",
  "results": [
    {
      "macAddress": "22:00:10:21:ca:54",
      "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 1.2345,
        "longitude": 123.4567,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
      },
      "loc": {
        "lon": 123.4567,
        "lat": 1.2345
      }
    },
    {
      "macAddress": "44:00:10:21:ca:14"
    },
    {
      "macAddress": "33:00:11:21:ca:54",
      "GeoCoordinate": {
        "latitude": 2.1345544523,
        "longitude": 123.45678,
        "unit": "DEGREES"
      },
      "loc": {
        "lon": 123.45678,
        "lat": 2.1345544523
      }
    }
  ]
}
```